# R - create a dual entry pivot table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pivot

I'm an R newbie so my apologizes if this is a simple question.
I use a lot excel to create "dual entries" tables. It's likely the name 'dual table' is not the most accurate but I wouldn't know how to describe it otherwise.
I basically start from big tables and then create a new one where I average the data grouping by two columns and then I display it as a matrix.
I will share with you a perfectly functional R example I coded myself.
My question is: is there an easier / better way to do it?
This is my working code:

```
require(dplyr)
df <- mtcars
output_var <- 'disp'
rows_var <- 'cyl'
col_var <- 'am'
output_name <- paste0("Avg. ",output_var)
one_way_table <- df %>%
  group_by(eval(parse(text=rows_var)),     eval(parse(text=col_var))  ) %>%
  summarise(output=mean(    eval(parse(text=output_var))     ))  

one_way_table <- data.frame(one_way_table, check.rows = F, check.names = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(one_way_table) <- c(rows_var, col_var, output_name)

unique_row_items <- unique(one_way_table[,rows_var])
unique_col_items <- unique(one_way_table[,col_var])
x_rows <- rep(unique_row_items, length(unique_col_items))
y_cols <- rep(unique_col_items, length(unique_row_items))

new_df <- data.frame(x = x_rows, y = y_cols, check.rows = F, check.names = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(new_df) <- c(rows_var, col_var)

new_df <- base::merge(new_df, one_way_table, by = c(rows_var, col_var), all.x=T)
m <- matrix(new_df[, output_name],    ncol= length(unique(new_df[,col_var])) )
df_matrix <- data.frame(m, check.rows = F, check.names = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Perhaps there's a way more efficient way to do it.
Notice how, since this will be coded inside a function, I had to use variable names do define what columns I want to use for the analysis.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution for your issue can come from `tidyverse`. Here an example reshaping your data and aggregating with mean:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- mtcars
#Code
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(cyl,am)) %>% filter(name=='disp') %>%
  group_by(cyl,am) %>% summarise(Mean=mean(value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = am,values_from=Mean)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl   `0`   `1`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  136.  93.6
2     6  205. 155  
3     8  358. 326
```

Which is close to `df_matrix` the final output of your code.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to pivot, this can be done in a more simple way.  We `select` the columns of interest and use `pivot_wider` with `values_fn` specifying as `mean` to be applied on the columns selected on `values_from`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>%
    select(cyl, am, disp) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = am, values_from = disp, values_fn = mean)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    cyl   `1`   `0`
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     6 155    205.
#2     4  93.6  136.
#3     8 326    358.
```